# AFNetworking - Check Downloaded bytes before resuming downloading of the file?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, afnetworking

I am using **AFDownloadRequestOperation** for downloading files over [AFNetworking Framework](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) and whenever i pause a file while downloading and then resume it later the ***setProgressiveDownloadProgressBlock*** starts returning values for the ***totalBytesRead*** from zero while the file is partially downloaded. Hence, the block after showing the remaining percentage of file calls ***setCompletionBlockWithSuccess***

But, i want to show proper progress in the progress bar so how should i get the proper percentage of the file Downloaded?

Answer (score -1):

This is what i use

```
 [operation setDownloadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesRead, long long totalBytesRead, long long totalBytesExpectedToRead) {
            NSLog(@"Operation%i: bytesRead               : %d", i, bytesRead);
            NSLog(@"Operation%i: totalBytesRead          : %lld", i, totalBytesRead);
            NSLog(@"Operation%i: totalBytesExpectedToRead: %lld", i, totalBytesExpectedToRead);

            if (totalBytesExpectedToRead > 0)
            {
                 self.progressView.progress = (float)totalBytesRead / totalBytesExpectedToRead;
            }
        }];
```

Introduced the check because of there the totalBytesExpectedToRead can become -1 sometimes which breaks the progressview progress smoothness [also note it is an issue from NSUrlconnection that the hrader returnes the -1 as expected size to read]

`(float)totalBytesRead / totalBytesExpectedToRead * 100` gives the percentage

Comment: Please read the full question.. I have already Implemented that.. i am asking fro something else..